# Incorrect binary version for python3 when using update-alternatives

Tags: python, 22.04, python3, binary

I've used Ubuntu for years but now I'm royally confused what's going on.

All suggests that I should be using `python3.9` but it actually is `python3.10`. Please help me debug this.

The **problem** is that I hoped the `update-alternatives` to replace `python` bin with specified path. In the case below I am expecting `python` to link to `python3.9` but it doesn't replace it and I'm ending up with Ubuntu22.04 default, i.e. `python3.10`.

Logs below show that `python` links to `/usr/bin/python` which links to `/usr/bin/python3.9` which is actually `python3.9`. But, when I check `python --version` it's actually `3.10`.

```shell
retyn@meland:~/projects/cracker$ python --version
Python 3.10.4
kretyn@meland:~/projects/cracker$ sudo update-alternatives --config python
There are 3 choices for the alternative python (providing /usr/bin/python).

  Selection    Path                 Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/bin/python3.9    3         auto mode
  1            /usr/bin/python3.10   1         manual mode
  2            /usr/bin/python3.8    2         manual mode
* 3            /usr/bin/python3.9    3         manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number: 3
kretyn@meland:~/projects/cracker$ python --version
Python 3.10.4
kretyn@meland:~/projects/cracker$ python3 --version
Python 3.10.4
kretyn@meland:~/projects/cracker$ which python
/usr/bin/python
kretyn@meland:~/projects/cracker$ ll /usr/bin/python
lrwxrwxrwx 24 root 24 Sep 11:20 /usr/bin/python -> /etc/alternatives/python*
kretyn@meland:~/projects/cracker$ ll /etc/alternatives/python 
lrwxrwxrwx 18 root 24 Sep 11:20 /etc/alternatives/python -> /usr/bin/python3.9*
kretyn@meland:~/projects/cracker$ /usr/bin/python3.9 --version
Python 3.9.14
kretyn@meland:~/projects/cracker$ /usr/bin/python --version
Python 3.9.14
kretyn@meland:~/projects/cracker$ python --version
Python 3.10.4
kretyn@meland:~/projects/cracker$ python
Python 3.10.4 (main, Jun 29 2022, 12:14:53) [GCC 11.2.0] on linux
```

Checking `type` and `type -a`

```
kretyn@meland:~$ type python
python is aliased to `python3'
kretyn@meland:~$ type -a python
python is aliased to `python3'
python is /usr/bin/python
python is /bin/python
kretyn@meland:~$ /bin/python --version
Python 3.9.14
kretyn@meland:~$ /usr/bin/python --version
Python 3.9.14
kretyn@meland:~$ python3 --version
Python 3.10.4
```

^ The last one is likely the cause. There's an alias `python=python3` and so `python` is replaced but `python3` isn't, which is why `python` is `python3.10`.

Comment: What problems does this apparent discrepancy cause?

Comment: You may find that `type python` or `type -a python` is more helpful than `which python`

Comment: 22.04 has python 3.10.4, 20.04 has python 3.8, and releases in between had python 3.9.

Comment: Since you do not given info as to what Ubuntu you are running hard to be clear.

Comment: @OrganicMarble it's a problem because it means that `update-alternatives` doesn't work as expected (by me). It was supposed to replace `python`  linking with specified path so insteadl 3.10 it should be 3.9.

Comment: You still haven't shown the output of steeldriver's suggestion of type -a python.   It will show aliases if any as well as the path.

Comment: @ubfan1 @steeldriver added `type` and `type -a`. I think this answered the question. Updated question with results and potential answer.